# SkiaSharp - how to move objects on canvas

Tags: c#, graphics, skiasharp

Is there a way to draw a line (or any shape) on a canvas, and then move that line?

I didn't see a way to do it, except maybe by constantly clearing and redrawing the entire canvas.  Is that the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the usual way - the canvas is tied to the update cycle of the view. SkiaSharp provides you with all the power, and does nothing.

If you have a complex drawing that takes a few milliseconds, and maybe could have areas cached, you can use temporary bitmaps. There is nothing stopping you from drawing to multiple bitmaps as things change, and then drawing all those bitmaps onto the screen when something needs updating.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your answer. If I have a big drawing, is it possible to divide it to boxes and save them as bitmaps for later use. For example, if my drawing is 1000px* 1000px, how can I draw the rectangular area contained in 501-1000px and 501- 1000px to a bitmap? My general idea is to pre-render chunks of the drawing in different levels of zoom to bitmaps and draw them instead of the whole lines, texts, etc. Do you think it is a plausible idea or I can do it much more efficiently via SkiaSharp.